# PHP - Read file in folder and subfolders and export to XML file

Tags: php, xml, scandir

I get this

> XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
>   Location: xxxxxxxxx
>   Line Number 2, Column 1

This is the code :

```
<?php

$xml_generator = new SimpleXMLElement('<data/>');

filesindir('assets/images/');
function filesindir($dirs) {
    $dirs = scandir($tdir);
    while ($file = readdir($dirs)) {
            if (($file == '.')||($file == '..')) {
            } elseif (is_dir($tdir.'/'.$file)) {
                filesInDir($tdir.'/'.$file);
            } else {
                $image = $xml_generator->addChild('image');  
                $image->addChild('name', $file);
            }
    }
}

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
$xml_generator->asXML('data.xml');
echo $xml_generator->asXML();
?>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post the XML Result (Source)?
If your Filename contains invalid XML,you have to append the Child as CDATA : http://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.addchild.php#104458

Comment: did you tried it with a simple sample? maybe there are illegal (for xml) characters within your test set (thinking of the content of the child, e.g. what would happen if there is an "<errortag" without closing in the content of the image?, you should escape those special characters or add the content as CDATA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many thing wrong .. look like you copied and merged so many codes ..

Try

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<data/>');

scanFiles(__DIR__, $xml);

function scanFiles($path, SimpleXMLElement $xml, $allowed = array("jpg","png")) {
    $list = scandir($path);
    foreach ( $list as $file ) {
        if ($file == "." || $file == ".." || ! in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowed))
            continue;
        $image = $xml->addChild('image');
        $image->addChild('name', $file);
        $image->addChild('size', filesize($file));
    }
}

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
$xml->asXML('data.xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <image>
    <name>a.jpg</name>
    <size>17129</size>
  </image>
  <image>
    <name>a2.jpg</name>
    <size>11100</size>
  </image>
  <image>
    <name>fake.png</name>
    <size>167</size>
  </image>
</data>
```

Comment: I use your code and run I got "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it" <data /> in the xml file nothing more what did I do wrong (again)?

Comment: I apologize for the bother and I think your code seems right. I used scanFiles('assets/images', $xml); to set my directory but I got nothing from it.. even I have files in my folder.

Comment: @ปลั๊ก แปดนิ้ว its ok .. am glad i was able to help

Comment: OK I finally got it the xml file is working completely... I just can't test it on the php file. So I think the xml's header is the culprit. But I have another question about your code. Does it not read the subfolder, isn't it? So how can I read the file in subfolders too? Thanks again...

Comment: Please do. that will help a lot. Thank you very much.